# Microsoft Entity validation Error Removal

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

When any Entity validation error occurred in any entity of the Dbcontext, it become persistent in the current context. If we pass valid data next time for any operation (Add, Update or Delete) previous validation error is still there and no operation is getting processed after that. I think this is a bug. It should be removed if new data is passed. How to remove that validation error from current context?

Comment: Please show us the part of your code that fails.

Comment: My code is working fine, When I send invalid model data, entity validation error happens. Now what I want is, in catch block I have to remove that entity validation error from the context. Since when next record of loop going to process with the same context, previous entity validation is still persist there and for all the records of list, same validation error is happening.

Comment: The rules of this site are: show code, describe what you want to achieve, and what you actually get. Otherwise it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: Got the solution on following link : http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/c1bff938-1789-4501-8161-3f38bc465a8b.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we adding Entity to Collection, its adding it to its Local Storage and we kept getting errors as the Local Storage of that Entity is not clear and still having old entries there. So you have to remove those validation error from current context. You can see the following link for more detail : http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/c1bff938-1789-4501-8161-3f38bc465a8b.aspx

```
if(ex is DbEntityValidationException dbException)
  {                 

   foreach (var eve in dbException.EntityValidationErrors)
    {                    
                    foreach (var ve in dbException.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(entity => entity.ValidationErrors))
                    {
                        sbErrorList.AppendLine(
                                                String.Format(" Entity: \"{0}\", Action: \"{1}\", Property: \"{2}\", Value: \"{3}\", Error: \"{4}\"",
                                                eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, 
                                                eve.Entry.State,
                                                ve.PropertyName,
                                                eve.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(ve.PropertyName),
                                                ve.ErrorMessage)
                                               );
                    }

                    #region Removing Entity Validation Error from current context : Rollback Changes                       


                    // checks the State property of the DbEntityEntry causing the error
                    switch (eve.Entry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            eve.Entry.State = EntityState.Detached; // changed to Detached so that the entry won't be considered a part of the DbSet for future calls
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            eve.Entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(eve.Entry.OriginalValues); // the modified values (the values causing the error) are flushed out by replacing them with the OriginalValues.
                            eve.Entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                            break;
                        case EntityState.Deleted:
                            eve.Entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged; // changed to Unchanged so that the entity is undeleted
                            break;
                    }
                    #endregion
                }                   
            }
```